# JavaScript library for Math, String, Array, canvas and location extensions

Tags: javascript, library

I just wanted to gather your opinion on my little JavaScript library. It features `Math`, `String`, `Array`, `canvas` and `location` extensions, as well as some useful animation and timing classes I came up with:

```
/* ====================== */
/* ======= Math ========= */
/* ====================== */

// Random number
Math.rand = function(min, max, float) {
    var random = Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
    return float ? random : Math.round(random);
};

// Random number with seed (not fully functional)
Math.srand = function(seed, min, max, float) {
    var code = 0;
    for (var i = 0, l = seed.length; i < l; i++) { code += seed.charCodeAt(i); }
    while (code > 1) { code/= 10; }

    var mod = code;
    var MAX_INT = Math.pow(2,32) - 1;
    var min = min != null ? min : -MAX_INT;
    var max = max != null ? max : MAX_INT;
    var random = mod * (max-min) + min;

    return float ? random : Math.round(random);
};

// 3.141592653589793 -> 180°
Math.toDegrees = function(angle) {
    return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
};

// 180° -> 3.141592653589793
Math.toRadians = function(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
};


/* ====================== */
/* ======= String ======= */
/* ====================== */

// string -> String
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

// "test".charAt(2, "oa") -> "toast"
String.prototype.charAt = function(index, replacement) {
    if (replacement == null) { return this.substr(index, 1); }
    else { return this.substr(0, index-1) + replacement + this.substr(index); }
};


/* ====================== */
/* ======= Array ======== */
/* ====================== */

// Compares values to an array object and returns the index
Array.prototype.compare = function(values) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        var matches = [];

        for (var ii = 0, ll = values.length; ii < ll; ii++) {

            if (this[i][values[ii][0]] == values[ii][1]) { matches.push(true); }
        }

        if (matches.length == values.length) { return i; }
    }
};

// Reaplces values in a numeric array
Array.prototype.replace = function(a, b) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (this[i] == a) { this[i] = b; }
    }
};


/* ====================== */
/* ======= Animation ==== */
/* ====================== */

// An advanced interval class which also calculates delta and fps
var Loop = function(callback, fps) {

    var _this = this;

    this.fps = fps ? fps : 60;
    this.real_fps = null;

    this.delta = 1;
    this.lastTime = +new Date;

    this.request = null;
    this.callback = callback;

    this.setFPS = function(fps) { this.fps = fps; };

    this.start = function() {

        // Timeout is used to specify a framerate
        this.request = setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimFrame(function() {
                _this.start();
                _this.delta = (+new Date - _this.lastTime) / (1000 / _this.fps);
                _this.real_fps = Math.round((1 + (1-_this.delta))*_this.fps);
                _this.callback();
                _this.lastTime = +new Date;
            });
        }, 1000 / this.fps);
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        clearTimeout(this.request);
    };
};

// An advanced timeout class which also calculates the current progress
var Ticker = function(start, duration, callback) {

    var _this = this;

    this.start = start;
    this.duration = duration;

    // TODO easing options

    this.reverse = false;
    this.auto_reset = false;
    this.auto_reverse = false;

    this.callback = callback ? callback : null;
    this.timeout = callback ? setTimeout(function() {
        _this.callback();
        if (_this.auto_reset || _this.auto_reverse) { _this.reset(); }
    }, this.duration) : null;

    this.status = function() {

        var end = this.start + this.duration;
        var current = +new Date;
        var duration = end - this.start;
        var difference = current - this.start;
        var progress = this.reverse ? 1 - (difference / duration) : (difference / duration);

        if (current >= end) { progress = this.reverse ? 0 : 1; }

        return progress;
    };

    this.reset = function() {
        if (this.auto_reverse) { this.reverse = this.reverse ? false : true; }

        this.timeout = this.callback ? setTimeout(function() {
            _this.callback();
            if (_this.auto_reset || _this.auto_reverse) { _this.reset(); }
        }, this.duration) : null;

        this.start = +new Date;
    }; 
};

// Unifies the HTML5 requestAnimationFrame function
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
            function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };
})();


/* ====================== */
/* ======= Canvas ======= */
/* ====================== */

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.center = function() {
    return {
        x: Math.round(this.canvas.width / 2),
        y: Math.round(this.canvas.height / 2)
    };
};

// Extends the canvas fillRect function to be able to draw round corners
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillRect = function(x, y, w, h, r1, r2, r3, r4) {
    if (r1 == null) {
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        this.lineTo(x + w, y);
        this.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
        this.lineTo(x, y + h);
        this.closePath();
        this.fill();
    } else {

        var r2 = r2 == null ? r1 : r2;
        var r3 = r3 == null ? r1 : r3;
        var r4 = r4 == null ? r2 : r4;
        r4 = r4 == null ? r1 : r4;

        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y + r1);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + r1, y);
        this.lineTo(x + w - r2, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + r2);
        this.lineTo(x + w, y + h - r3);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w - r3, y + h);
        this.lineTo(x + r4, y + h);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - r4);
        this.closePath();
        this.fill();
    }
};

// Extends the canvas strokeRect function to be able to draw round corners
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.strokeRect = function(x, y, w, h, r1, r2, r3, r4) {
    if (r1 == null) {
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        this.lineTo(x + w, y);
        this.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
        this.lineTo(x, y + h);
        this.closePath();
        this.stroke();
    } else {

        var r2 = r2 == null ? r1 : r2;
        var r3 = r3 == null ? r1 : r3;
        var r4 = r4 == null ? r2 : r4;
        r4 = r4 == null ? r1 : r4;

        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y + r1);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + r1, y);
        this.lineTo(x + w - r2, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + r2);
        this.lineTo(x + w, y + h - r3);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w - r3, y + h);
        this.lineTo(x + r4, y + h);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - r4);
        this.closePath();
        this.stroke();
    }
};


/* ====================== */
/* ======= Document ===== */
/* ====================== */

// Simple cookie handling object
var Cookie = {
    set: function(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + location.pathname;
    },

    unset: function(name) { Cookie.set(name, "", -1); },

    get: function(name) {
        var search = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]*);");
        var result = search.exec(document.cookie);
        return result ? result[1] : null;
    }
};

// Returns the value of the specified GET parameter (equivalent to PHP's $_GET[name])
location.get = function(name) {
    var search = new RegExp(encodeURIComponent(name) + "=([^&]*)&?");
    var result = search.exec(location.search);
    return result ? result[1] : null;
};

function include(file) {
    var dir = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].getAttribute("src").match(/([\w_-]+)\/[\w_-]+\.js/)[1];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", dir + "/" + file);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function createRequestObject() {

    var request, browser = navigator.appName;

    if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    { request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    else
    { request = new XMLHttpRequest(); }

    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some tips.

## 1)

Avoid using java keywords. In Math.rand, there is a variable called `float`.
Try calling it `toFloat`.

## 2)

It's best not to browser sniff. Detect for features instead.

Old Code:

```
function createRequestObject() {

    var request, browser = navigator.appName;

    if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    { request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    else
    { request = new XMLHttpRequest(); }

    return request;
}
```

New Code:

```
function createRequestObject() {
    var request;
    if (ActiveXObject) {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return request;
}
```

## 3)

Try not to repeat yourself.

Old Code:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.strokeRect = function(x, y, w, h, r1, r2, r3, r4) {
    if (r1 == null) {    
        this.beginPath();
        //...
        this.closePath();
        this.stroke();
    } else {
        //...
        this.beginPath();
        //...
        this.closePath();
        this.stroke();
    }
};
```

New Code:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.strokeRect = function(x, y, w, h, r1, r2, r3, r4) {
    this.beginPath();
    if (r1 == null) {    
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
    this.closePath();
    this.stroke();
};
```

## 4)

Make functions as small as possible. Try adding functions to the prototype instead of creating them inside the constructor.

Old Code:

```
var Loop = function(callback, fps) {
// ...
  this.start = function() {

        // Timeout is used to specify a framerate
        this.request = setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimFrame(function() {
                _this.start();
                _this.delta = (+new Date - _this.lastTime) / (1000 / _this.fps);
                _this.real_fps = Math.round((1 + (1-_this.delta))*_this.fps);
                _this.callback();
                _this.lastTime = +new Date;
            });
        }, 1000 / this.fps);
    };

//...
};
```

New Code:

```
Loop.prototype.start = function () {
    // Timeout is used to specify a framerate
            var _this = this;
    this.request = setTimeout(function () {
            requestAnimFrame(function () {
                _this.start();
                _this.delta = (+new Date() - _this.lastTime) / (1000 / _this.fps);
                _this.real_fps = Math.round((1 + (1 - _this.delta)) * _this.fps);
                _this.callback();
                _this.lastTime = +new Date();
            });
        }, 1000 / this.fps);
};
```

## 5)

Rename `String.prototype.charAt` to `String.prototype.replaceByIndex`

## 6)

`this.fps = fps ? fps : 60;` is the same as `this.fps = fps || 60;`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! One question though: In the prototype example, how do I create the necessary reference `_this` used to have ?

Comment: @elias94xx Create a reference outside the function to `this` called `_this`. Refer to the updated code example.

Comment: Oh of course, got confused a little. :)